# JSON format is being returned with missing data using C# (HTTPWEBREQUEST)

Tags: c#, json

I'm working with JSON and C# ( HttpWebRequest ). Basically I have application to download a JSON from and API REST, but the problem is when I download it, the JSON comes missing some data, it seems that is cutting some data, with wrong structure. If I use a software which does the same thing that I'm developing, this problem doesn't happen. I'm sure that is something with my code, if I'm missing something. Here is my code:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MyURL");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        string authInfo = "user" + ":" + "pass";
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;


        // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.          

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();


        using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\Stores.txt");

            sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Comment: Information you have provided is not enough to give a complete answer. Can you provide expected JSOn and JSON you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.its works in my code.

```
 public static async Task MethodName()
    {

        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false })
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = Program.getAuthenticationHeader();
                string filterQuery = Program.getURI().ToString();

                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(filterQuery).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {

                    var streamContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\test\Stores.Json", FileMode.Create);
                    streamContent.CopyTo(fs);
                    streamContent.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue with your Http request (GET). 
Step 1 - If you have a working software with the API, use **Fiddler** to analyse what is the  http GET request it sends. You need to check the header info as well. 
Step 2 - Compare the Http request with the HttpRequest you have created. There can be missing parameters etc.